# Jquery Validation on dynamically populated fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, validation

Im having issues getting Jquery Validation to work properly on dynamically populated fields. First off im using asp.net so I need my name fields to stay the same because on the server side im pulling that array of information splitting it and updating a database.

```
         <form id="insert_additions" action="http://yahoo.com" method="post">
<label>
    Name1<input type="text" name="testing" value="" required/>
</label>
<label>
    Name2<input type="text" name="box_setup"  required value="" />
</label>
<label>
    Comments:&nbsp<input type="text" name="comments" value="" /></label><br />
<div id="work"></div>
<br />
<hr align="left" width="50%"/>
<span style="margin: 0 0 0 300px;">
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="button" id="addbutton" class="flatBtn" value="Add Another Project Line" /></span>
</form>
```

This here is the code that is adding the fields

```
var work_count = 2;
$("#addbutton").click(function () { //sets up the validator
    //Html to create a new field
    var newField = "<hr align='left' width='50%'>\
        <label>Name1\
        <input type='text' name='testing"+work_count+"' required size='8'  value='' \
        </label>\
        <label>Name2\
        <input type='text' name='box_setup' required value='' />\
        </label>\
        <label>Comments:\
        <input type='text' name='comments' value='' />\
        </label>\
    ";
    $("#work").before(newField);
    $('input[id="testing'+work_count+'"]').rules("add", {  // <- apply rule to new field
        required: true
    });
    work_count++;
});
```

As you can see I have tried adding the validate.rules() with in the javascript so that when it add's the new input's into the page it could also insert new rules. I have tried making the id variable but im not sure what im doing wrong. Validation is only working on the first set of fields. I have read and tried implementing various solutions that I have read on this website but im just lost I have started beating my head against my keyboard. Any help would be great I appreciate and love this web forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just setting the attribute through jquery?

```
$('input[name="testing'+work_count+'"]').attr('required', true);
```

btw, there is no id attribute on your added inputs.
so:

```
$('input[id="testing'+work_count+'"]').rules("add"
```

should be

```
$('input[name="testing'+work_count+'"]').rules("ad
```